# ¿Como crear multi subdominios desde carpetas?

Tags: .htaccess

Como crear multi subdominios con htaccess desde carpetas, digamos tengo mis carpetas así
`/folder1/folder2/` y quiero que mi dirección sea así `folder1.folder2.dominio.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdominio.mipagina.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mipagina.com/subcarpeta/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

La primera y segunda línea (Options y RewriteEngine) sirven para habilitar la reescritura de urls.

La siguiente línea RewriteCond creará una condición, lo que significa que siempre que la url llamada coincida con subdominio.mipagina.com se cumplirá y ejecutará la regla siguiente, sino simplemente la omitirá. [NC] sirve para que no distinga entre mayúsculas y minúsculas y los . sirven para escapar el punto ya que es un caracter especial de los rewrites.

La última línea RewriteRule va a recoger cualquier contenido que enviemos contra ese subdominio con (.*), es decir, que si entramos a subdominio.mipagina.com/algomas, se guardará como variable la parte algomas y la incluiremos después. La siguiente parte es el destino http://www.mipagina.com/subcarpeta/$1, la subcarpeta a la que lo queremos enviar. El $1 sirve para colocar la variable que hemos dicho antes, por tanto al cargar el subdominio que he comentado lo redirigiría a http://www.mipagina.com/subcarpeta/algomas, por lo que podríamos entrar a cualqueir subcarpeta y archivo que se haya escrito en el navegador de forma automática. Por último [L,NC,QSA] significa:

- L = Última acción (si coincide y se redirecciona no sigue buscando más reglas, no hace falta)
- NC = No Case Sensitive, no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas
- QSA = Recoge todas las variables query que podamos enviar, es decir, si mandamos ?var=algo, nos enviará también esto a la nueva dirección

Answer (score 3):

Veo un poco complejo realizar una re-escritura de más de un subdominio, ya que se necesitaría reemplazar en el rewriteRule los . por /

Para un solo subdominio, bastaría con:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# No reescribimos directorios reales...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ... ni archivos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\.]+)\.dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ %1/$2 [QSA,L]
```

finalmente, esto serviría para dominio del tipo:

```
subd.domain.com -> <path_base>/subd
subd1.subd.domain.com -> <path_base>/subd1.subd
```

espero te sirva

saludos